# React App and Chrome DevTools local overrides not working?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to debug a chunk of js code from a CSR React app using chrome dev tools local overrides (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides). I am changing the files in the sources tab and save them into being local overrides.

Every change I enable in local overrides is visible inside the chrome dev tools overrides tab after refresh. But the local changes do not apply to the React app I am seeing. After every reload I am seeing the react app as it would be without any changes/overrides.

I have tried to do local overrides through the chrome dev tools on other non react sites, there it is working.

Am I missing something or are local chrome devtools overrides not possible with a CSR React app?

EDIT: Note I am trying to apply Chrome dev tools overrides to a deployed production CSR React App.

Comment: I thing this is a bug that should be fixed by Google. There is no point to let users modify and save a file, if the changes are not taken into consideration.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well I figured it out myself

For anyone else stumbling up on this:

In a React app you have to look into the chrome devtools network tab and open the chunk script in source tab. Then you can add it to overrides and modify the files.

Comment: The endless list of chunk-*.js files? Impossible to figure out which file to edit. You can't search variables and/or filenames, since those have been replaced with "chunk-*.js"

Answer (score 9):

You may encounter this problem if the website uses **Service Workers**.

To fix it go to **Application** tab and check **Bypass for network**

Comment: I really was not expecting this to work because it sounds so random, but yeah, it's like magic! What a poor UX from Chrome.

Comment: Developer tools -> Application -> Service Workers -> Bypass for network (check)